# Instagram API: How to specify count and offset for GET Likes/Comments?

Tags: get, social-networking, instagram

How to get list of users, who like certain media, but with `offset` and `limit` parameters?

And how to use pagination?

When i retrieve response `GET /media/{media-id}/likes?access_token={access_token}&count=5`, it always return `200 likes and pagination=<null>`.

How to iterate through all comments and likes?

Answer (score 1):

Offset is not available. But there is `MAX_ID` parameter, where you can specify the `ID` of the last item you got.

You can find further information about the endpoints [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem... Instagram API doesn't allow you to paginate or limit the amount of likes returned. I solved this by limiting my `foreach` statement and you can probably do the same thing with a `for` statement.

Comment: my part of project is interaction with Instagram. so, result of my must be slice of array of objects(likes or comments) :\

Comment: hah, i will use this technique too, but when i try to get likes from media, it gives me not all likes (200 from ~1200) :( it is sad :(

Comment: You could probably load the likes into an array and then again use the array splice if you wanted! Good luck!

Comment: i do this, but on specific query "GET likes from specific media_id" instagram send me response not with full likes, but only a part. what should i do? how can i said to instagram, that i want all of his data (it doesn't send me pagination for this :( )

Comment: When you get the Instagram response for `likes:` you can format that data into an array. Then you'll need to use the array_splice() function that I mentioned above and you can paginate through the array with `POST` and `GET` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked, but in case you just want to get like count, you can do:

```
GET /media/{media-id}
```

And check the `--data-likes-count` on the JSON response.